# Source code of tzupdater.jar

Tags: java, timezone

I'm using tzupdater.jar to update timezone issues in java but for clearance/approval I need the source code of this jar. I checked the oracle website but they are providing only only. No source code available.

Can someone help me to get the source code tzupdater.jar ???

Comment: Do you also need the source code of the JDK/JRE to install it? Or the Oracle database? I guess not. These are all commercial products provided by Oracle without source code. You should make that clear to your clearance/approval team - this is just part of the Oracle product offering.

Comment: That means their is no way around to get the source code of tzupdater.jar as these are commercial products of Oracle? Please suggest if their is a way to get that.

Comment: tzupdater is no open source! It is a commercial Oracle product, and therefore a [special licence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html) is offered.

Comment: @rahulsharma If your company has an open-source-only policy, then you're out of luck (but then I assume you're using OpenJDK rather than Oracle's JDK). If it doesn't have that policy, you just need to explain to clearance/approval that this is vendor-supported product and should be treated just like other vendor-supported products, such as the JDK itself.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Thanks.  Its clearly mention in license file regarding the source code distribution.